# Asp.net Identity User relationship with Model

Tags: asp.net, dependencies, identity, circular-dependency

I want to create an one to many relationship between ApplicationUser and another model. The problem is that my model class is in another class library and I cannot reference it to my startup project because it creates a circular dependency. Any ideas what I can do? Publication is the class library Project.Core and ApplicationUser is in another class library

```
public class Publication
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }

        //Here is the problem
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }

 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public List<Publication> Publications { get; set; }
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            return userIdentity;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's hard to understand your question from the information you post.
Pleas detail the problem with context, so that we can help you.

If your one to many means `one Publication to many ApplicationUser`, you should modify `AppliationUser` to `ICollection<ApplicationUser>`.

```
public class Publication
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }= new List<ApplicationUser>();
    }
```

Comment: You models are same as mine, and it works for me. I think the problem existed in your reference. Please post it :P